# Is It possible to set environment variable and echo it in a single line batch script?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

```
set A=2 && echo %A%
```

This does not echo A as 2 in windows. Is there any way to do it?

```
A=2 ; echo $A
```

works in bash. I want a similar behavior on windows

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Seems like a minor stylistic concern to me.

Comment: Might be necessary in an alias? Or make for easier coding in a script that generates other scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this, here are two of them:

- `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION&set "foo=bar baz"&echo.!foo!&endlocal`
- `set "foo=bar baz"&for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('set foo') do if "%%~A"=="foo" echo.%%B`

Edit: Added check to "filter" set results for 2nd solution, thanks Johannes Rössel

Comment: Note that for loops use %%X for variables in batch files, and just %X in the "terminal"

Comment: For the second variant, you should hope that there aren't more variables starting with `foo`.

Comment: The first one as it is prints !foo!

Comment: @Kamal: You must put it in a batch file

Answer (score 0):

Note the `!` surrounding `A` instead of `%`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET A=2 & ECHO !A!
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: @Kamal It worked on XP and Vista for me. Try copy/pasting into a .CMD file and then running in a new command window.

Comment: @Anders I see you did post similar code. For such a small snippet of code, there are bound to be similarities.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@Anders answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2733027/281084), I tweaked his solution to something that gives you a bit more flexibility:

```
set foo=bar&for /f %a in ('echo ^%foo^%') do @echo %a
```

Output:

```
bar
```

This enables you to do string replacement too:

```
set foo=bar&for /f %a in ('echo ^%foo^:a^=o^%') do @echo %a
```

Output:

```
bor
```

Edit: added some carets to fix @jeb's remark.

Comment: This doesn't work reliable. If you run it again but change `bar` to `ccc` it stills echo `bar`